# Functions For Calling Specific Elements

Tags: functions, pages, templates

The php functions `get_header()` and `get_footer()` both call the *header.php* and *footer.php* files.

Could I create a page like *element.php* and have a function call it (like `get_element()`), where I would have it on the pages that I use that function, but not others, or is this not possible?  I searched the documentation, but I don't think I know the official name for what I'm looking for - in essence a function that calls an element for some pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) would do the trick.

In `element.php` you could simply call `get_template_part( 'element-item' );`, which would then include the `element-item.php` file from your theme.

You could wrap this up in a function if you wanted to, e.g. `get_element()`.

```
function get_element() {
    get_template_part( 'element-item' );
}
```

This approach would allow you to add logic into the `get_element()` function so that it only gets the template part under certain conditions and it would keep the `element.php` template from our example cleaner since the logic would be bundled up in `get_element()`.